# Waiting for backgroundworker

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have two methods which do some work by using BackgrounderWorker. If i run first method then it does some work in background and same goes for second method. But what I want is that second method should wait untill method one worker is started.

Code

```
private void Method1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RunFirstWorker();
}

private void Method2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RunFirstWorker();
    RunSecondWorker();
}
```

Comment: from the question and the code - it is not obvious the relations between Method1 and 2 in the code and method one and two in the text and first and second worker in the code... what runs what and who waits on whom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use event object ([`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) or [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx)) to synchronise execution of these functions. Create the event in non-signalled state and wait for it at the beginning of `RunSecondWorker()`'s `DoWork` event handler. Set the state of this event to signalled at the end of `RunFirstWorker()`'s `DoWork` event handler.

In your original code snippet `Method1()` and `Method2()` were GUI callbacks (methods executed on the GUI thread) so you don't want to block them (you don't want to wait for event in any of those methods themselves but in BackgroundWorker callback - `DoWork` event handler).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps return the IAsyncResult in F1 and pass it into the worker in f2, and then call waitone on the AsyncWaitHandle at the start of the f2 worker?

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx

@Nikita - I didn't mean call from within F1 and F2, the original poster says they are using background workers.

Comment: May I have a comment for the -1 please?

Answer (score -1):

Edited: (Looking at other answers) OK - the problem is how and WHEN are you going to wait for F1. BackgroundWorker has event - RunWorkerCompleted which is executing on the main thread. If you need to do some logic there and wait for it to be done - then you cannot wait, that will cause deadlock. One option is to use Application.DoEvents() to pump up msgs - but it may cause some unexpected behavior.